# Logarithm and sum of powers

Tags: logarithms

If $$2^x + 2^y = 2^{f(x,y)},$$
then $f(x,y) = $?

I tried to take logarithm of both sides but ended up with an answer that I know cant be right.

Comment: Taking the base 2 log of both sides is the right approach.  What was your answer?  Why can't it be right?  It is not a simple thing like plus or times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take the $\log_2$ of both sides, since that's the only way you can get the $f(x,y)$ in polynomial/solve-able form. You'll get:

$$f(x,y)=\log_2(2^x+2^y)$$

And that's pretty much it. We can't apply any logarithm property here. This is one such expression where taking the $2^x$ common may result in lesser readability than it currently has, hence, leaving it in this form is much better.

Comment: Okay I see what I did. The right hand side simply doesn't reduce. Still it seems like the mathematicians would create a function like that. Or at least give it a name.

Comment: @R.Emery "Still it seems like the mathematicians would create a function like that" You mean to say they would invent a new notation to depict such expressions?

Comment: I am saying that f(x,y) would be a very interesting and possibly a very useful function.

Comment: @R.Emery Well, given the way these notations work, if you ever write a book/research paper of your own, just stick this new $f(x,y)$ at the top of your book and then use it everywhere. If enough mathematicians find it useful, this new $f(x,y)$ might go viral in all maths books ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the 2^x common"?

Comment: @R.Emery I meant $f(x,y)=\log_2((2^x)\cdot(1+2^{y-x}))$ which can be split as $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$.

Comment: I wrote this:http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Generalization#Numbers or assembled it at least. I was thinking about putting it there.

Comment: @R.Emery I would not suggest putting a not-so-well known notation in a public wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^x + 2^y = 2^{f(x,y)},$$
$$2^x + 2^y = e^{f(x,y)\ln(2)},$$
$$\ln(2^x + 2^y) = f(x,y)\ln(2),$$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(2^x + 2^y)}{\ln(2)}$$